# symfony edit form with file

Tags: forms, file-upload, symfony

I have a problem with the file widget of my edit form.

In [the Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html), at the end of the first paragraph, it says :

> When creating a form to edit an already persisted item, the file form
> type still expects a File instance. As the persisted entity now
> contains only the relative file path, you first have to concatenate
> the configured upload path with the stored filename and create a new File class:
>
> ```
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
>
> // ...
>
> $product->setBrochure(
>     new File($this->getParameter('brochures_directory').'/'.$product->getBrochure())
> );
> ```

However, even if I apply this on my form, my file widget still show "no file chosen" (if my translation is ok).
Moreover, since the total form must have a file attached, the user have to attach the file again.

How can I manage to show that a file is already uploaded, and give only the opportunity to update the file with another ?

EDIT : related SO post : [Non blank file input field in Symfony2 form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373551/non-blank-file-input-field-in-symfony2-form)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a non-mapped field to your form that shows the file name or even a thumbnail of the file (you will need to create a getter for it.
E.g

```
$builder->add('file_preview', 'text', array('label' => 'Existing File', 'required' => false, 'mapped' => false));
```

Or if you display the form in your twig using single fields, just add in the name/preview.
Something like;

```
<div class="my-form">
    <div class="{{ obj.file.name }}"</div>
    <div>{{ form_widget(form.file) }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But can't I keep this widget and autocomplete it with the file previously uploaded ?

Comment: That is not how file inputs in html work, they are for adding a new file. When editing an object that has a file you either ignore the file field and only allow other data to be changed or give the option to upload another file

Comment: But then a file is never `NotBlank` if you can edit it ? I find it wierd that such a common thing is not explained in the doc

Comment: @DanChaltiel use validation groups to only check file not blank on create, not on edit.

Comment: Yes, see my edit about that... II've been searching the whole doc on how to do it for hours but I don't find anything clear about it :-s